# Campos calculados en DataTable JQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo un DataTable en el que quiero calcular:
1-Subtotal:precio * cantidad
2-base imponible=subtotal por alicuota de iva

Entre otras cosas.

```js
var q = [];
var details;
var data = '{"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b":{"id":"108","cantidad":"2","nombre":"22NOMBRE  OTTRA","precio":"25340.69","alicuota":"21.00","unique_id":"a3c65c2974270fd093ee8a9bf8ae7d0b","total":50681.38},"ed3d2c21991e3bef5e069713af9fa6ca":{"id":"98","cantidad":"26","nombre":"22NOMBRE  OTTRA","precio":"30.33","alicuota":"21.00","unique_id":"ed3d2c21991e3bef5e069713af9fa6ca","total":788.58},"c74d97b01eae257e44aa9d5bade97baf":{"id":"16","cantidad":"10","nombre":"22NOMBRE  OTTRA","precio":"4.04","alicuota":"27.00","unique_id":"c74d97b01eae257e44aa9d5bade97baf","total":40.4}}';


  var keys = Object.keys(data);
  $.each(keys, function(i, item) {
    details = data[item];
    q[q.length] = {
      "nombre": item,
      "details": details
    };
  });

  c = {
    data: q
  };

var t = $('#factura').DataTable({
  data: q,

  columnDefs: [{
      type: "num",
      symbols: "$",
      targets: 3,
      width: "8%"
    },
    {
      type: "num",
      symbols: "$",
      targets: 1,
      width: "8%"
    },
    {
      type: "num",
      symbols: "$",
      targets: 4,
      width: "8%"
    },
    {
      type: "num",
      symbols: "$",
      targets: 5,
      width: "8%"
    },
    {
      "targets": [0],
      "visible": false
    }
  ],

  columns: [{
      data: "details.id",
    },
    {
      data: "details.cantidad",
      title: "CANT"
    },
    {
      "data": "details.nombre",
      title: "NOMBRE"
    },
    {
      "title": "P/U",
      "data": "details.precio"
    },
    {
      title: "SUBTOTAL",


      render: function() {
        var did = details.id;
        var table = $("#factura").DataTable();

        var column = table.columns().data();
        return details["precio"];
      }
    },
    {
      title: "Alicuota",


      render: function() {
        return details['alicuota'];
      }
    },


    {
      width: "5%",
      title: "ELIMINAR",

      className: "center",
      defaultContent: "<input type='radio' class='e' name='seleccionado'/>",

    }
  ],



  language: {
    "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix": "",
    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
    "sUrl": "",
    "sInfoThousands": ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
      "sFirst": "Primero",
      "sLast": "Último",
      "sNext": "Siguiente",
      "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
      "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
      "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    },

    responsive: true,

  },

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="factura">

  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Pero el problema es que se pisan los valores calculados con el ultimo registro insertado en la session php.

Intente insertar el id en una columna hidden:

```
   {data:"details.id"},
  {
     "targets": [0],
     "visible": false
   }
```

Pero no se como referirme a la fila de dicho id para calcular subtotales y demas. alguina sugerencia?

Aqui una captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Subtotal y alicuota son siempre iguales

Comment: Si puedieras plasmar el problema con la opción **Fragmento Javascript/HTML/CSS** podríamos replicar el error y ver la solución, ¿Podras hacerlo?

Comment: Listo ya agregue un array en string supliendo el de php, como veras es un objeto y adjunto imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo solucione de la siguiente manera, el campo id oculto no fue necesario.

```
    {title: "SUBTOTAL",
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            var t=$("#factura").DataTable();
          var row=t.row(meta.row).data().details;
          var sub=row.precio * row.cantidad
          return "$"+sub.toFixed(2) ;
      } },
```